# Does BigQuery support Dynamic SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to execute multiple statements in BigQuery using stored procedures. This is a generic stored procedure which can invoked for any table, hence need to execute dynamic statements on any table.

Is there EXEC() like thing in BigQuery to execute dynamically generated queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As of 5/20/2020, BigQuery [released](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#May_20_2020) dynamic SQL feature for you to achieve the goal.

> Dynamic SQL is now available as a beta release in all BigQuery regions. Dynamic SQL lets you generate and execute SQL statements dynamically at runtime. For more information, see [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate).

For your scenario, you could have a generic procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE myTableOperations(tableName STRING) 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("SELECT col1 FROM ", tableName, " WHERE ...");
  ...
END
```

Comment: It's great! But I think IMMEDIATE is a badly named command. Why did you not choose a name like DYNAMIC? Is ASYNC version planned?

Comment: Part of the reason is to follow SQL standard, which says EXECUTE is used with a prepared statement, which BQ doesn't have.